# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; cannot login with other users except sys user, Oracle Database 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sysdba

I have setup  Oracle Database 12c on my local machine. It was working fine initially but now I cannot login to users' account except the sys user. I have altered users' passwords and tried logging in using **SQLPlus** and **SQL DEVELOPER**.

```
ALTER USER XYZ IDENTIFIED BY XYZ;
```

I have also checked the parameter **SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON** which is set to **FALSE**.
The users, that I am trying to connect are created in pluggable database i.e **orclpdb** and they do exist in the pluggable database.
I can only login to sys user of pluggable database and root.
The username and passwords are **correct**, I don't know why the oracle is behaving weirdly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why was `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON` set to false? That is deprecated in 12c. This is a known issue that I encountered many times.

[Case-Insensitive Passwords and ORA-1017 Invalid Username or Password](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/upgrd/case-insensitive-passwords-ora-1017-invalid-username-password.html)

> The Oracle Database 12c release 2 (12.2) default authentication
> protocol is 12 (Exclusive Mode). This protocol requires case-sensitive
> passwords for authentication. Review your options if you have earlier
> release password versions.
>
> Starting with Oracle Database 12c release 2 (12.2), the default value
> for the SQLNET.ORA parameter ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER is changed
> to 12. This parameter refers to the logon authentication protocol used
> for the server, not the Oracle Database release.
>
> By default, Oracle no longer supports case-insensitive password-based
> authentication; only the new password versions (11G and 12C) are
> allowed. The case-insensitive 10G password version is no longer
> generated.
>
> ...
>
> If the following conditions are true, then you may have accounts that
> are prevented from logging into the database after upgrading to 12.2:
>
> You are upgrading a server that has user accounts created in an
> earlier Oracle Database release.
>
> User accounts created in the earlier release use a case-insensitive
> password version from an earlier release authentication protocol, such
> as the 10G password version.
>
> Earlier release user accounts have not reset passwords.
>
> The server has been configured with SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON set to
> FALSE, so that it can only authenticate users who have a 10G
> case-insensitive password version.
>
> ...
>
> **Option for Servers with Accounts Using Only 10G Password Version**
>
> After you upgrade to Oracle Database 12c release 2 (12.2), complete
> the following procedure to enable accounts using the 10G password
> version:
>
> Log in as an administrator.
>
> Edit the SQLNET.ORA file to change the
> SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER setting from the default, 12, to
> 11 or lower. For example:
>
> SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11
>
> After you change to a more permissive
> SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER setting, expire users’ passwords
> to require them to change their passwords. For detailed information,
> refer to Oracle Database Security Guide.

Comment: I set SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON  to TRUE and it worked. Thanks.